# What RoundingMode constant works 100% like Math.round?

Tags: java, rounding

I mean is there any [RoundingMode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html) constant describing exactly what `Math.round(arg)` does? I understand that Math.round does not formally use any RoundingMode class/object.

So far I found no analogy. There is a **partial** analogy - in situations like 1.5, -1,5 etc ties are broken just as in `RoundingMode.CEILING` (*"towards positive infinity"*). But `RoundingMode.CEILING` analogy cannot work for other arguments (1.7, -1.1), so it cannot be a 100% analogy.

So I found absolutely no 100% analogy in all RoundingMode constants which makes me think I was inattentive somewhere. *List of constants in RoundingMode class shall have constants for all widely-used rounding modes, right?*

So why there is no 100% analogy in RoundingMode class?

Here is the [comparison table](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html) for RoundingMode class constants and their behaviour.

P.S. `Math.floor(arg)` method behaves exactly like `RoundingMode.FLOOR`, `Math.ceil(arg)` behaves exactly like `RoundingMode.CEILING`.

Answer (score 6):

`Math.round()` works like `RoundingMode.HALF_UP` for positive numbers and like `RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN` for negative numbers.

The reason is that `Math.round()` rounds ties toward positive infinity and there is no mode that does that.

To clarify, both modes will work exactly like `round()`, except for ties (i.e. numbers like `xxx.5`), such as 5.5 and -5.5, which will round to 5 and -5 for `HALF_DOWN`, 6 and -6 for `HALF_UP`, but -5 and 6 for `round()`.

What you are looking for is `RoundingMode.HALF_CEILING` but it doesn't exist.