# What kind of rounding is `Math.round(arg)`? What exact term to use to describe this way of rounding?

Tags: java, rounding

What kind of rounding is `Math.round(arg)`?

It does not fully/exactly fint into any of RoundingMode constants. But this question is not about RoundingMode constants. It is about all principal ways how rounding can be done and is done (most widely used practice).

So what wikipedia category does it fully fits into? What exact term to use to describe this way of rounding?

[All kinds of rounding (wiki)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Comparison_of_rounding_modes)

**THIS QUESTION IS DIFFERENT FROM [What RoundingMode constant works 100% like Math.round?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49448040/what-roundingmode-constant-works-100-like-math-round) BECAUSE THIS QUESTION IS ASKING ABOUT *GENERALLY ACCEPTED MATHEMATICAL NAME OF Math.round() METHOD* (as wikipedia defines it, for example), WHILE MENTIONED QUESTION IS ONLY ABOUT *SPECIFIC CONSTANTS IN RoundingMode class*.**

Comment: Did you read javadoc?

Comment: It's `RoundingMode.HALF_UP`.

Comment: @lexicore It is not RoundingMode.HALF_UP. Simple counterexample: Math.round(-5.5) = -5 (because it rounds to positive infinity), while RoundingMode.HALF_UP shall give -6 (same as for 5.5). I read javadoc carefully, besides this question IS NOT ABOUT JAVADOC, BUT ABOUT WIDELY ACCEPTED MATHEMATICAL TERMINOLOGY (while closely related to java)

Answer (score 3):

As found in the [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round(double)):

> **public static long round(double a)**
>
> Returns the closest long to the argument, with ties rounding up.
>
> **Special cases:**
>
> - If the argument is NaN, the result is 0.
> - If the argument is negative infinity or any value less than or equal to the value of Long.MIN_VALUE, the result is equal to the value
>     of Long.MIN_VALUE.
> - If the argument is positive infinity or any value greater than or equal to the value of Long.MAX_VALUE, the result is equal to the value
>     of Long.MAX_VALUE.
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> **a** - a floating-point value to be rounded to a long. Returns:
>   the value of the argument rounded to the nearest long value.
>
> **See Also:**
>
> *Long.MAX_VALUE, Long.MIN_VALUE*

So to keep it simple: It uses `RoundingMode.HALF_UP` for positive numbers and `RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN` for negative numbers. It always goes towards infinity.

Comment: @JornVernee Thanks for the heads up, I will edit my answer. Condolences for the half-truth.

Comment: Math.round(-5.5) = -5 (towards POSITIVE infinity)

Answer (score 1):

There's enough information in the [table of rounding modes you linked to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Comparison_of_rounding_modes) to figure this out if you call `Math.round` on each of the values in the **Value** column and note the outputs.  Here they are in [Java REPL](http://www.javarepl.com/term.html):

[image: results of rounding on Java REPL]

As you can see, those results match the round to nearest **Round half up (towards +∞)** column in the table.