# How can I adapt my code using Math.round and remainder on integer-valued FP double into a Java code using SIMD instructions?

Tags: java, math, simd

I am trying to adapt this java code in order to be compatible with SIMD instructions.

```
    int[] arr1 = {50002, 51000, 52040, 53078, 54065, 55004, 56077, 57073, 58020, 59000, 60095, 61046, 62051, 63018, 64480, 65460};
    int[] arr2 = {50, 57, 60, 63, 66, 70, 73, 74, 80, 81, 87, 88, 90, 92, 96, 103};
    int[] result = new int[16];
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        double a = arr1[i] / (double) arr2[i];
        int b = (int) ((Math.round(a * a) - 1) % 25) + 1;    // I need help to adapt this line of code.
        result[i] = b;
    }
```

I am trying to write a new java code adapted to SIMD instructions:

```
    int[] arr1 = {50002, 51000, 52040, 53078, 54065, 55004, 56077, 57073, 58020, 59000, 60095, 61046, 62051, 63018, 64480, 65460};
    int[] arr2 = {50, 57, 60, 63, 66, 70, 73, 74, 80, 81, 87, 88, 90, 92, 96, 103};
    int[] result = new int[16];
    var species = IntVector.SPECIES_PREFERRED;
    var Vec1 = IntVector.fromArray(species, arr1, 0);
    var Vec2 = IntVector.fromArray(species, arr2, 0);
    var RESULT = Vec1.mul(Vec1).div(Vec2.mul(Vec2);    // I need help to write the lines highlighted in the previous code.
    RESULT.intoArray(result, 0);
```

I simply cannot find a way to adapt the formula.

Edit 1:
As my knowledge is limited (beginner), I notice now that it is more complex than I thought.
So, let me explain better what the function does:
In fact, arr1 has 50 million prime numbers (from 2 to 982451653) and arr2 has 5000 numbers (from 1 to 5000).
There are 2 loops, the first loop (arr2) and the second loop (arr1).
The real java code is:

```
    int[] arr1 = {2, 3, 5, 7, ... , 982451609,  982451629,  982451653}; // 50 million prime numbers.
    int[] arr2 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ... , 4998, 4999, 5000};
    for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
        int[] result = new int[50000000];
        for (int j = 0; j < 50000000; j++) {
        double a = arr1[j] / (double) arr2[i];
            int b = (int) ((Math.round(a * a) - 1) % 25) + 1;    // I need help to adapt this line of code.
            result[j] = b;
        }
        // do something with result[] before discarding it
    }
```

For example:
arr1[1034158] is 16050707 and arr2[452] is 453

sqr(arr1/arr2) is equal to 1255428344.7599

The result of the formula should be 20 (round 1255428344.7599 -> 1255428345. Then, 1255428345 minus 1255428325 is 20.

Comment: Most SIMD ISAs don't have integer division or modulo.  But modulo by a constant can be done using the high half of a multiply by a magic constant, which you then shift.  (To get a quotient, which you then multiply and subtract.)  Converting back to integer at the right place will make this more efficient.

Comment: Or you could do the remainder calculation in double-precision FP like I think you're currently doing in the Java expression.  The fact that your operands are actually integer-valued doubles probably allows some optimizations that `fprem` couldn't use, although if `a` can be `2^31 - 1`, squaring that is way larger than 2^52, above which integers start getting rounded to multiples of powers of 2, so a simple divide / round / multiply / subtract might have a lot of rounding error.  But if you have FMA that might not be a problem.

Comment: Can your real code assume value-ranges are smallish and/or non-negative like your example?  I notice that `arr1[]` values would fit in u16, and that `a` values are much smaller than that, small enough that `round(a*a)` can fit exactly in a float32 (effectively a 24-bit mantissa) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format#Precision_limitations_on_integer_values .  Which could let us avoid widening to 64-bit `double` elements.  On x86 it might still not be worth doing the remainder with integer since high-half int32 mul is inconvenient, and x86 only has FMA for FP.

Comment: Earlier I meant the C/C++ `fmod` function; `fprem` is a legacy x86 instruction.  Apparently Java supports the `%` operator on float / double values instead of having it only as a function call.  Anyway, doing `x - floor(x / 25.0) * 25.0` with an FMA might be good enough, like the way GCC and clang vectorize if I write it that way: https://godbolt.org/z/8xPrvacPh   Or `x * (1.0/25.0)` to allow a multiply instead of another divide, if that inexact constant doesn't cause problems.

Comment: Do you have to use `Math.round()`?  It uses a rounding mode that isn't supported in hardware on x86.  (out of the modes in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html , x86 `roundpd` supports FLOOR, CEIL, and HALF-EVEN (the IEEE default mode), and truncation toward 0.  `Math.round` [isn't any of the other modes, though](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49448040/what-roundingmode-constant-works-100-like-math-round)).  I'm trying to find any other Java rounding function; is it calling `round` in a `MathContext` or is that only for BigDecimal?

Comment: I tidied up the integer-modulo C version (https://godbolt.org/z/ThYfYvT7d) and added AArch64 asm output to show it auto-vectorizes there, too.  That asm vectorization strategy can hopefully be implemented in Java but I'm not posting an answer because I don't know Java's SIMD library.  Again, `float` instead of `double` would be at least twice as efficient, more elements per vector, faster conversion, and faster division per vector (on recent Intel, like maybe another factor of 2 throughput difference between `vdivps` and `vdivpd`)

Comment: @PeterCordes, I have just edited my question with more details. I have read many times that SIMD improves java performance, but this is beyond my knoledge. Please, check the new text. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, so the highest `a` is close to full range `int32`, and these are always non-negative.  The `arr2[i] = i+1` divisor is loop-invariant for the inner loop.  If the rounding error isn't a problem, you can hoist the reciprocal, like `double inv_i = 1.0 / (i+1);`  and `double a = arr1[j] * inv_i;`.  I assume the `int result[]` array for each `i` is saved somewhere or at least read once before being discarded?

Comment: Anyway yes, SIMD should be able to speed this up, but `double % double` isn't an operation that CPUs can do directly, so don't expect to find it as a SIMD intrinsic; at best as a vectorized `fmod` library function.  So the goal here is to do that "manually" with something that's precise enough to round to the right integer for the range of inputs you need to support.  `remainder = x - round(x / y) * y` is one way to approach it, with either integer or FP math, as I showed in two C++ versions.  What matters is the asm instructions; hopefully we can get a JVM to use similar asm instructions.

Comment: @PeterCordes, you're wright, the `int result[]` array for each `i` is read before being discarded.